# Trying to locally share a folder between Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, 18.04

I am trying to share a folder between Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04, but it doesn't work. I am trying to setup a folder to share called `gravity-spy` onto my U17.10 and I want to do it as simply as possible.

- I want to be able to simply right click on the folder I want to share then click on **Properties** then on **Share** tab click on **Share this folder** (other 2 checks are left them blank for anonymous access and if user can edit/delete folder - I don't need those features)
- Then on my other machine which in this case is Ubuntu 18.04 I go to **Other locations**, I type into the box **Connect to server** `smb://[myusername]@[computername]/[name-of-the-shared-folder]` click on <kbd>Connect</kbd>, and I am getting an screen where they want me to add a Domain and a Password, but what is the domain? I think this is only for Windows computer (the domain I mean), isnt it? Whatever I write in those 2 boxes I get an error - `Can't access this location`

What is the simplest way to connect Ubuntu 17.10 -> Ubuntu 18.04 using the smb protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE METHOD 1**: I think the easiest way is to use ssh command - scp, but before using it you have to create ssh access to both computers. [You can read how to do this here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04) When you are ready and all setup and tested the `ssh` command and it is working, then you can simply write (if you want to transfer files from remote to local machine (or just switch the destination and source if you want to transfer from local to remote):

```
scp source destination
```

for example scp [remote-user]@[remote-ip]:[full-path-to-file-folder] [full-path-to-local-folder]

---

**METHOD 2:**
I manage to do it this way i dont know if it is simplest, but it worked at the end of the day:

1. to make it executable `sudo chmod 777 /[path]/[to]/[shared-folder]`
2. installed samba `sudo apt install samba`
3. edited the conf file of samba `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`
4. Added this at the bottom of the file:

## read only:

```
[foldername]
comment = Gravity Spy Shared Folder
path = /[path]/[to]/[shared-folder]
```

## writable

```
[foldername]
comment = Gravity Spy Shared Folder
path = /[path]/[to]/[shared-folder]
read only = No
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
directory mode = 0777
```

5. Save the file and tested with `testparm` if the file have any errors
6. Restart samba server with `systemctl restart smbd`
7. Allowing port 139 with `sudo ufw allow 139/tcp`
8. Allowing port 445 with `sudo ufw allow 445/tcp`
9. Create password for samba `sudo smbpasswd -a [your-username]`
10. Then on my other computer i typed: `smb://[ip-address-of-my-server]/[folder-name]`
11. Click on Login with user and then

    - type your username you typed at point 9
    - domain leave it `WORKGROUP`
    - type your password you typed at point 9

and VOILA!

BTW: to find your ip address you can type `ifconfig -a` and your ip address should start with `192.182.*.*` it should be near this word `inet 192.168.100.7`